# Firefox 3 and Safari doesn't load some parts of CSS

Tags: css, firefox-3

I have a page that works in IE 7,8,9; Chrome and FF6 but I have some problems loading a part of style in FF3.

This is a part of the .css file:

```
.recipe_search_results table td ul.trait_icons {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

.recipe_search_results table td ul.trait_icons li {
    display: inline; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell us what does not work as intended. But since you are running into problems in Firefox here is a helpful hint for you: Install the [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon to your Firefox 3 and analyze your page and the effective style sheets being applied to your elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry if it was quite clear. I can't use the FireBug cuz it's not compatible with Firefox 3.

Anyway, that part of the CSS doesn't apply in FF3. If I use the FireBug in FF6 and I delete that part of the code it seem like in FF3. But there are others parts of the CSS with the same problem.

Comment: You can install older versions that fit to your Firefox browser version: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/

Comment: Thanks, at least I can do the test directly. But display:inline; doesn't apply. I don't understand.

Comment: I had a </div> in the bad place, so IE and Chrome are tolerant with this and FF6 but not FF3. Thank you vey much!